# With .each() iterate through a list and create select options with the li's text

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm trying to iterate through a list, get the text of it's items and create and then inside a select, create an option with each of the list items 
text, but I just get the last one.

```
$(".categories ul li a").each(function(i){

  console.log($(this).text());

  $(".filters-select").html("<option value=." + $(this).text() + ">" + $(this).text() + "</option>" );
})
```

Why does the console log works and outputs the 4 items that I have, but it's not creating 4 option tags and just one?

The HTML structure looks like this:

```
<li class="categories">Categorías
  <ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="http://localhost:8888/category/novedades/">novedades</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-2"><a href="http://localhost:8888/category/nueva/">Nueva</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="http://localhost:8888/category/otros/">Otros</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="http://localhost:8888/category/sin-categoria/">Sin categoría</a>
</li>
</ul></li>
```

Comment: use `append()` not `html()` you get the **only last one because the previous one it is being  overridden by the next one**. like `$(".filters-select").append("<option value=." + $(this).text() + ">" + $(this).text() + "</option>" );`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.append()` and not `.html()` since html will override everytime its called.

`$(".filters-select").append("<option value=." + $(this).text() + ">" + $(this).text() + "</option>");`

**Demo**

```js
$(".categories ul li a").each(function(i) {

  console.log($(this).text());

  $(".filters-select").append("<option value=." + $(this).text() + ">" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="categories">Categorías
  <ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="http://localhost:8888/category/novedades/">novedades</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-2"><a href="http://localhost:8888/category/nueva/">Nueva</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="http://localhost:8888/category/otros/">Otros</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="http://localhost:8888/category/sin-categoria/">Sin categoría</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<select class="filters-select"></select>
```

Comment: Such a silly mistake on my part, thank you. Accepting in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you use html() this is what happen for EACH loop:

1. You get the data you want
2. You create your option
3. You change the HTML of ".filter-select" by the current option

So each loop you delete the previous.

This is an other solution than using append() you can use I think:

```
var option_content = "";  // I create an empty var
$(".categories ul li a").each(function(i){

  option_content += "<option value=." + $(this).text() + ">" + $(this).text() + "</option>";

});

$(".filters-select").html(option_content);
```

You build your data for each loop, then you add it in your "filter-select" element.

Hope it helps